# Approach to a Bin Packing sql problem

Tags: sql

I have a problem in sql where I need to generate a packing list from a list of transactions.

### Data Model

The transactions are stored in a table that contains:

- transaction id
- item id
- item quantity

Each transaction can have multiple items (and coincidentally multiple rows with the same transaction id).  Each item then has a quantity from 1 to N.

### Business Problem

The business requires that we create a packing list, where each line item in the packing list contains the count of each item in the box.

Each box can only contain 160 items (they all happen to be the same size/weight).  Based on the total count of the order we need to split items into different boxes (sometimes splitting even the individual item's collection into two boxes)

So the challenge is to take that data schema and come up with the result set that includes how many of each item belong in each box.

I am currently brute forcing this in some not so pretty ways and wondering if anyone has an elegant/simple solution that I've overlooked.

### Example In/Out

We really need to isolate how many of each item end up in each box...for example: 

Order 1:

- 100 of item A
- 100 of item B
- 140 of item C

This should result in three rows in the result set:

- Box 1: A (100), B (60)
- Box 2: B(40), C (120)
- Box 3: C(20)

Ideally the query would be smart enough to put all of C together, but at this point - we're not too concerned with that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is this a homework problem, asked out of curiosity, or a real-world problem? It sounds interesting, but a bit constructed.

Comment: I agree with sleske, if only because items are rarely of uniform size & weight -- not even items of the same type!

Comment: Nope, it's a real world problem. We're packaging shipments for food products from online purchases.   The reason they're the "same weight" is an approximation I made to simplify the problem.  They're different varieties of the same product which each have a different recipe.  The main need for this query is to help the team actually mixing and baking the products to know what needs to be baked and which ones go in which shipping container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT SUM([Item quantity]) as totalItems
     , SUM([Item quantity]) / 160 as totalBoxes
     , MOD(SUM([Item Quantity), 160) amountInLastBox
FROM [Transactions]
GROUP BY [Transaction Id]
```

Let me know what fields in the resultset you're looking for and I could come up with a better one

Comment: The problem with this is that I really need to isolate how many of each item end up in each box...for example:
I have 100 of item A, 100 of item B and 140 of item C.  This should result in:
Box 1: A (100), B (60)
Box 2: B(40), C (120)
Box 3: C(20)

Ideally the query would be smart enough to put all of C together, but at this point - we're not too concerned with that.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking a cursor's the only way to go, but it is 3:30 AM, so lemme sleep on it and we can probably use a more efficient WITH clause

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and all I could achieve was expanding the rows to the number of item counts in a transaction, and grouping them into bins. Not very elegant though.. Moreover, because string aggregation is still very cumbersome in SQL Server (Oracle, i miss you!), I have to leave the last part out. I mean putting the counts in one single row..

#### My solution is as follows:

Example transactions table:

```
INSERT INTO transactions
(trans_id, item, cnt) VALUES
('1','A','50'), 
('2','A','140'), 
('3','B','100'), 
('4','C','80');
GO
```

Create a dummy sequence table, which contains numbers from 1 to 1000 (I assume that maximum number allowed for an item in a single transaction is 1000):

```
CREATE TABLE numseq (n INT NOT NULL IDENTITY) ;
GO
INSERT numseq DEFAULT VALUES ;
WHILE SCOPE_IDENTITY() < 1000 INSERT numseq DEFAULT VALUES ;
GO
```

Now we can generate a temporary table from transactions table, in which each transaction and item exist **"cnt"** times in a subquery, and then give numbers to the bins using division, and group by bin number:

```
SELECT bin_nr, item, count(*) count_in_bin
INTO result
FROM (
  SELECT t.item, ((row_number() over (order by t.item, s.n) - 1) / 160) + 1 as bin_nr
  FROM transactions t 
  INNER JOIN numseq s
  ON t.cnt >= s.n -- join conditionally to repeat transaction rows "cnt" times
) a
GROUP BY bin_id, item
ORDER BY bin_id, item
GO
```

Result is:

```
bin_id item count_in_bin
1      A    160
2      A    30
2      B    100
2      C    30
3      C    50
```

In Oracle, the last step would be as simple as that:

```
SELECT bin_id, WM_CONCAT(CONCAT(item,'(',count_in_bin,')')) contents
FROM result
GROUP BY bin_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the prettiest answer but I am using a similar method to keep track of stock items through an order process, and it is easy to understand, and may lead to you developing a better method than I have.

I would create a table called "PackedItem" or something similar. The columns would be:

```
packed_item_id (int) - Primary Key, Identity column
trans_id (int)
item_id (int)
box_number (int)
```

Each record in this table represents 1 physical unit you will ship.

Lets say someone adds a line to transaction 4 with 20 of item 12, I would add 20 records to the PackedItem table, all with the transaction ID, the Item ID, and a NULL box number. If a line is updated, you need to add or remove records from the PackedItem table so that there is always a 1:1 correlation.

When the time comes to ship, you can simply

```
SELECT TOP 160 FROM PackedItem WHERE trans_id = 4 AND box_number IS NULL
```

and set the `box_number` on those records to the next available box number, until no records remain where the `box_number` is NULL. This is possible using one fairly complicated UPDATE statement inside a WHILE loop - which I don't have the time to construct fully.

You can now easily get your desired packing list by querying this table as follows:

```
SELECT box_number, item_id, COUNT(*) AS Qty
FROM PackedItem
WHERE trans_id = 4
GROUP BY box_number, item_id
```

Advantages - easy to understand, fairly easy to implement.
Pitfalls - if the table gets out of sync with the lines on the Transaction, the final result can be wrong; This table will get many records in it and will be extra work for the server. Will need each ID field to be indexed to keep performance good.