# Distribute large quantities over multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, bin-packing

I have a simple Order table and one order can have different products with Quantity and it's Product's weight as below

| OrderID | ProductName | Qty | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | ProductA | 2 | 24 |
| 101 | ProductB | 1 | 24 |
| 101 | ProductC | 1 | 48 |
| 101 | ProductD | 1 | 12 |
| 101 | ProductE | 1 | 12 |
| 102 | ProductA | 5 | 60 |
| 102 | ProductB | 1 | 12 |

I am trying to partition and group the products in such a way that for an order, grouped products weight should not exceed 48.

**Expected table look as below**

| OrderID | ProductName | Qty | Weight | GroupedID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | ProductA | 2 | 24 | 1 |
| 101 | ProductB | 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 101 | ProductC | 1 | 48 | 2 |
| 101 | ProductD | 1 | 12 | 3 |
| 101 | ProductE | 1 | 12 | 3 |
| 102 | ProductA | 4 | 48 | 1 |
| 102 | ProductA | 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 102 | ProductB | 1 | 12 | 2 |

Kindly let me know if this is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a bin-packing problem to me, it's well-trodden ground: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501132/approach-to-a-bin-packing-sql-problem https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/11/bin-packing-part-1-setting-a-baseline/ https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/a-set-based-solution-for-the-bin-packing-problem etc

Comment: Hello @Dai, Thanks for replying, I am expecting one result set, but in that I want an extra column, Grouped ID,  based on the weight, qty of the product. Please have a look on my expected table for insights. Thank you

Comment: @JackFrost how serious about efficiency? [Bin packing is NP-complete](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/) and there are various ways you could form groups. The example you posted is too regular to be realistic as weights are so regular. In real life different algorithms would result in different solutions resulting in more or fewer groups and eg shipments. It would be better to use a bin packing library in eg Python. SQL Server 2017+ allows calling Python scripts through sp_execute_external_script

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am okay even if the query takes time to return value, as background job will use the query

Comment: I agree, it's going to be very hard to write this efficiently in SQL, you should use a procedural language for this

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bin packing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/) problem which is non-trivial in general. It's not just NP-complete but superexponential, ie the time increase as complexity increases is *worse* than exponential. Dai posted a link to [Hugo Kornelis's article series](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2011/10/bin-packing-part-5-set-based-iteration/) which is referenced by everyone trying to solve this problem. The set-based solution performs really bad. For realistic scenarios you need iteration and preferably, using bin packing libraries eg in Python.

For production work it would be better to take advantage of [SQL Server 2017+'s support for Python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?view=sql-server-ver16) and use a bin packing library like [Google's OR Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin_packing) or the binpacking module. Even if you don't want to use `sp_execute_external_script` you can use a Python script to read the data from the database and split them.

The question's numbers are so regular though you could cheat a bit (actually quite a lot) and distribute all order lines into individual items, calculate the running total per order and then *divide the total by the limit* to produce the group number.

*This works only because the running totals are guaranteed to align with the bin size.*

Distributing into items can be done using a [Tally/Numbers table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/), a table with a single `Number` column storing numbers from 0 to eg 1M.

Given the question's data:

```
declare @OrderItems table(id int identity(1,1) primary key, OrderID int,ProductName varchar(20),Qty int,Weight int)

insert into @OrderItems(OrderId,ProductName,Qty,Weight)
values
(101,'ProductA',2,24),
(101,'ProductB',1,24),
(101,'ProductC',1,48),
(101,'ProductD',1,12),
(101,'ProductE',1,12),
(102,'ProductA',5,60),
(102,'ProductB',1,12);
```

The following query will split each order item into individual items. It repeats each order item row as there are individual items and calculates the individual item weight

```
select o.*, Weight/Qty as ItemWeight
from @OrderItems o inner join Numbers ON Qty >Numbers.Number;
```

This row:

```
1   101 ProductA    2   24
```

Becomes

```
1   101 ProductA    2   24  12
1   101 ProductA    2   24  12
```

Calculating the running total inside a query can be done with :

```
SUM(ItemWeight) OVER(Partition By OrderId 
             Order By Itemweight
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

The `Order By Itemweight` claus means the smallest items are picked first, ie it's a `Worst fit` algorithm.

The overall query calculating the total and Group ID is

```
with items as (
    select o.*, Weight/Qty as ItemWeight
    from @OrderItems o INNER JOIN Numbers ON Qty > Numbers.Number
)
select  Id,OrderId,ProductName,Qty,Weight, ItemWeight,
       ceiling(SUM(ItemWeight) OVER(Partition By OrderId 
             Order By Itemweight
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/48.0) 
       As GroupId
from items;
```

After that, individual items need to be grouped back into order items and groups. This produces the final query:

```
with items as (
    select o.*, Weight/Qty as ItemWeight
    from @OrderItems o INNER JOIN Numbers ON Qty > Numbers.Number
)
,bins as(
    select  Id,OrderId,ProductName,Qty,Weight, ItemWeight,
       ceiling(SUM(ItemWeight) OVER(Partition By OrderId 
             Order By Itemweight
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/48.0) As GroupId
    from items
)
select 
    max(OrderId) as orderid,
    max(productname) as ProductName,
    count(*) as Qty,
    sum(ItemWeight) as Weight, 
    max(GroupId) as GroupId
from bins
group by id,groupid
order by orderid,groupid
```

This returns

| orderid | ProductName | Qty | Weight | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | ProductA | 2 | 24 | 1 |
| 101 | ProductD | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 101 | ProductE | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 101 | ProductB | 1 | 24 | 2 |
| 101 | ProductC | 1 | 48 | 3 |
| 102 | ProductA | 4 | 48 | 1 |
| 102 | ProductA | 1 | 12 | 2 |
| 102 | ProductB | 1 | 12 | 2 |

Comment: Hello @Panagiotis, Thanks a lot for the query, I was testing with your query, it is working fine but I have noticed that it is failing in one scenario ```insert into OrderItems(OrderId,ProductName,Qty,Weight) values (120,'ProductA',1,30)(120,'Producty',1,30), (120,'Productz',1,18), (120,'ProductB',1,18)``` . where weight 30 & 30 (which exceeds 48) are grouped with same group ID not sure why.

Comment: I said this would *only* work for those numbers, which align *exactly* with the bin sizes. This that all bins can be filled completely except the last. This means there would be no case where an `ItemWeight` would be partly in one bin and partly in another. That's what happens here. And that's why this is a complex problem.